# How to run 10 AWG ground wire along basement wall?

Tags: mounting, grounding-and-bonding, ground

What would be a sturdy and efficient way to mount a single 10 AWG solid core ground wire along an unfinished concrete basement wall (connectors, fasteners, etc)? I'm connecting a server rack ground bar to ground to prevent static electricity build up. I planned on coming down from ceiling between the receptacles in picture.

[image]

Comment: No reason to overthink this. Sleeve it in 1/2” PVC and just use a 1 hole strap to secure that to the wall.

Comment: That's EMT metal conduit with metal boxes and covers. **It is already a ground path**.  If that also goes back to the panel in EMT,       there is no need for any green or bare wires.

Comment: Is that EMT back to the panel, or sleeves up the basement wall?  If the rack manufacturer calls for a dedicated ground, do what is called for.

Comment: @Harper The EMT only goes along wall, from receptacle to joists.

Comment: ah, so right now the conduit is just a cable shield, in the NM wiring method. Then you can fit junction boxes at the joists, turning it into the conduit wiring method, and run the ground along the joists, grounding the upper box.  Conduit carries ground to the lower box, and you bring your ground wire in there via a knockout and cable clamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional would be drill holes, insert plugs and use a cable clip with a nail or screw. This is a lot of work. Alternatives would be to glue it.

As to connecting it, the Good way to do it is with cable lugs. That requires tools to install. Solid core may also be terminated directly to the ground lugs of the rack.

But note that you are not bonding to dissipate static. You're bonding to ensure that all conductive surfaces are at the same potential. Concrete is conductive, so if the concrete is earthed, and the rack is not, you may get a potential difference between the rack and concrete. This can shock you. For dissipating static electricity, a high resistance is commonly used to **avoid** dangerous currents trough the dissipation wire.

Comment: So @vidario are you saying that grounding the server rack with a #10 wire is unnecessary? It would certainly seem to be. The receptacles are grounded and presumably the grounds in the power cords go into the servers and connect to anything that should be grounded. The metal rack is the only thing possibly not grounded. If the rack has rubber pads on the bottom or paint on the metal it would not be bonded to the concrete floor. So wouldn't it suffice to have a bonding strap from the rack go to some convenient ground connected to one of the receptacles, say just a ground on one of the servers.

Comment: For the purpose of static electricity it is not needed. For ensuring bonding, it's certainly a very good practice, and may be required, depending on your electric code.

Comment: I withdraw my suggestion of connecting to one of the servers, but what about a #10 wire screwed to the rack and the other end of the wire attached to the ground of a 3-prong plug. This would be plugged into one of the receptacles to make the ground.

Comment: I would generally avoid plugs for ground, as they may be unplugged.